# Char automatically converts to int (I guess)

Tags: c

I have following code

```
char temp[] = { 0xAE, 0xFF };
printf("%X\n", temp[0]);
```

Why output is `FFFFFFAE`, not just `AE`?

I tried

```
printf("%X\n", 0b10101110);
```

And output is correct: `AE`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Using `-pedantic` compiler switch will diagnose the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you're getting, `FFFFFFAE`, is a result of the `char` data type being signed. If you check the value, you'll notice that it's equal to -82, where -82 + 256 = 174, or `0xAE` in hexadecimal.

The reason you get the correct output when you print `0b10101110` or even 174 is because you're using the literal values directly, whereas in your example you're first putting the 0xAE value in a `signed char` where the value is then being sort of "reinterpreted modulo 128", if you wanna think of it that way.

So in other words:

```
    0   =    0 = 0x00 
    127 =  127 = 0x7F
    128 = -128 = 0xFFFFFF80
    129 = -127 = 0xFFFFFF81
    174 =  -82 = 0xFFFFFFAE
    255 =   -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF
    256 =    0 = 0x00
```

To fix this "problem", you could declare the same array you initially did, just make sure to use an `unsigned char` type array and your values should print as you expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    unsigned char temp[] = { 0xAE, 0xFF };

    printf("%X\n", temp[0]);
    printf("%d\n\n", temp[0]);

    printf("%X\n", temp[1]);
    printf("%d\n\n", temp[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
AE
174

FF
255
```

Answer (score 1):

https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

According to the man page, `%x` or `%X` accept an `unsigned integer`. Thus it will read 4 bytes from the stack.

In any case, under most architectures you can't pass a parameter that is less then a `word` (i.e. `int` or `long`) in size, and in your case it will be converted to `int.`

In the first case, you're passing a `char`, so it will be casted to `int`. Both are signed, so a signed cast is performed, thus you see preceding `FF`s.

In your second example, you're actually passing an `int` all the way, so no cast is performed.

If you'd try:

```
printf("%X\n", (char) 0b10101110);
```

You'd see that `FFFFFFAE` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a smaller than `int` data type (as `char` is) to a variadic function (as `printf(3)` is) the parameter is converted to `int` in case the parameter is `signed` and to `unsigned int` in the case it is unsigned.  What is being done and you observe is a **sign extension**, as the most significative bit of the `char` variable is active, it is replicated to the thre bytes needed to complete an `int`.

To solve this and to have the data in 8 bits, you have two possibilities:

- Allow your `signed char` to convert to an int (with sign extension) then mask the bits 8 and above.

  ```
  printf("%X\n", (int) my_char & 0xff);
  ```
- Declare your variable as `unsigned`, so it is promoted to an `unsigned int`.

  ```
  unsigned char my_char;
  ...
  printf("%X\n", my_char);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This code causes [**undefined behaviour**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). The argument to `%X` must have type `unsigned int`, but you supply `char`.

Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen; including, but not limited to, extra F's appearing in the output.